# How do I read text from a UIView.textField?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uikit

I am trying to play with the Apple sample app tutorial(ToDO List) code and I am at the last stage where I am trying to read from the textField of type UIView. The compiler keeps complaining that there is no such field as a text field for the UIView.textField object. Any ideas on how I can retrieve the text inside the textField to be passed on to the storage/data store?

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if (sender != self.saveButton) return;
    if (**self.textField.text.length** > 0) {
        self.toDoItem = [[ToDoItem alloc] init];
        self.toDoItem.itemName = **self.textField.text**;
        self.toDoItem.completed = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: are those asterisks actually in your code?

Comment: they were meant to make that text bold for this question.

Comment: Do you have a property for the textfield?

Answer (score 0):

**1**. Create a property in the .h file of the view controller like below:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField;
```

**2**. in the .m file synthesize it like so:

```
 @synthesize myTextField;
```

**3**. Then go to the interface builder and right click on the File's Owner then drag a line from myTextField to the TextField on the View.

**Note**: Also do not forget to tell the UITextField who its delegate will be. Select ViewController.xib and control drag from the UITextField to Files Owner; when you release the mouse, select **delegate** from the popup.
Or in your viewDidLoad method:

```
self.myTextField.delegate = self;
```

Now you can read text from your textField.

Comment: You don't need to synthesize it I believe, why not just access it like self.myTextField?